# How can I create a multiline entry in /etc/hosts?

Tags: linux, hosts

We have a situation where we have many aliases for an IP address and these aliases need to be defined in `/etc/hosts`. Rather than having extremely long lines containing all the aliases for an IP address, I would like to be able to continue listing the alias on the next line so that I can maintain the formatting and keep the file readable.

I have not been able to find any documentation on how to achieve this.

For example:

```
# in /etc/hosts
10.11.11.11    alias1.localhost  alias1 \
               alias2.localhost  alias2 \
               alias3.localhost  alias3 \
               alias4.localhost  alias4
```

This results in the first line being processed, but none of the subsequent lines are:

```
$ python -c "import socket; print(socket.gethostbyname('alias1'))"
10.11.11.11

$ python -c "import socket; print(socket.gethostbyname('alias2'))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I've tried this in various formats, including removing the backslashes, but nothing seems to work.

We are on Ubuntu 16.04.

Is this possible?

Comment: You are allowed to use the same IP address on more than one line.

Comment: @AlexP I've read that it can cause problems: https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2004/06/msg00449.html

Answer (score 2):

Not really, no. From digging around in the [glibc sources](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html) looking for `/etc/hosts` and then for `_PATH_HOSTS` one may [encounter `_gethtent`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=resolv/compat-gethnamaddr.c;h=259378b2be2d5f639531f032dd2d85588a2a49aa;hb=HEAD#l734) which appears to have no code related to `\` handling.

If you do want this feature, you would need to patch the `libc`, which is probably not the best of ideas.

A better idea may be to template `/etc/hosts` such that the sources used to be build the file can be formatted as you desire, and then the templated `/etc/hosts` contains the necessarily long lines. This could be done with configuration management.